# Code Signing Error with a Development Provisioning profile

Tags: ios, react-native, provisioning-profile

Alright, so I have experience with Android and now I am working with React Native and I am struggling with a very simple thing with is setting up an iOS build for production.

Some background, I dont yet have an iOS Developer Account so I built locally with my Personal Team account. Also, I am not invited into this customer´s account, but they sent me the provisioning profile and the p12.

I set up the build machine (I am using App Center) and the build complains with this:

Code Signing Error: No profiles for 'XXXXXXXXX' were found:  Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'XXXXXXX'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.

I understand the bundle identifier needs to match the AppID but the PP is a wildcard one. I event tried adding the prefix into the bundle identifier, same error.

At this point, I don´t mind building the IPA locally with the PP they sent me if that is what I need. I just can´t find a proper guide on this and it is driving me nuts.

Thanks

Comment: You would require 3 things from client : 1. Certificate 2. Private key 3. Provision profile.

Comment: But you won't be able to push the build to iTunesConnect since you are not invited to the team.

Comment: @Nitish Thanks for your input! So I imported the p12 certificate since I have the pass, and I actually was able to create the archive. Now I am testing the development export to see if I can distribute the IPA. Will they be able to distribute that build if I send that one to them? Or will they need to build again and upload it by themselves?

Comment: Certificate is for distribution ? If yes, then they would need Xcode installed with them and their appID configured with Xcode. Then they can upload the build to iTunesConnect via Application Loader

Comment: Excellent. So I was able to made the ipa now. I only had to change to manually sign as I was having automatic build. Now, I want to install the IPA in a test device and it says that a valid PP was not found. I am trying to import the PP into the device, but it does not do anything after I choose it. I know this is very beginner level but I am strugglingso thank you for helping.

Comment: You can't directly test that ipa file. You need to use TestFlight app for that.

Comment: And for TestFlight, build needs to be uploaded on iTunesConnect.

Comment: So I am in deadlock. Basically if I am not invited to a customer team or I have a valid iOS developer account I can build but I can´t test on devices. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But since you have your own account. Why don't you use it to install app on your device(s) on which you want to test. But if that number is quite big, I am afraid, you are in deadlock.

Comment: @Nitish No, it is OK. I mean I was able to test, now I just want the customer to test the app, but could not install the release on their device because I have a personal team account. If I send the IPA can they upload it to testflight? Sorry to bother yuo so much but this is really helping.

Comment: Like I said, they would need Xcode. And you need to assist the client to upload the build